# MySQL search string begins with string first, but also return any results that contain string

Tags: mysql, string, search, wildcard

I want to search a column for a value, and return the values that start with the search first, and then return any that contain it.

For instance:
Search: John
John Doe
John Cook
Johnny Appleseed
Bill Johnson
Ted Johnson
The Johnsons

Right now the simplest way seems to be to query like, "WHERE Name LIKE 'john%'", and then query again for WHERE Name LIKE '%john%', AND merge the results. It seems like there's probably a way to do this in one query though. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do a conditional order like so

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE Name LIKE '%john%'
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN Name LIKE "john%" THEN 1 
         WHEN Name LIKE "%john%" THEN 2
         WHEN Name LIKE "%john" THEN 3 -- # -- you can add more conditions like so
         ELSE 4
    END
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/729ea/2)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a simple wild cards on both sides of your string but order your results that starts from your provided string

```
select * from t where col like '%john%' order by  col like 'john%' desc
```

`order by  col like 'john%' desc` will result as boolean 0/1 so the records that starts with john will be shown first and then other matching records will be returned